# How to check what is the format of a datetime column on my sql server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table `XPTO` on my SQL Server.
There is a column `DATEEXAMPLE datetime`.

When I select the date it comes: `2013-12-02 16:14:13.023` (`aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss`).

Is this the real datetime format?
How can I change this format to "aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

The data is stored in an internal format that is format-less.  The format is something you see on output (and deal with in input).

How you handle the format depends on the database.  In SQL Server, you use the `convert()` function, which is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  Personally, I have a strong preference for the ISO standard format, which is what you are seeing.

Note:  you can also change the default display format in SQL Server by changing the default format (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/173907/)).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
convert(varchar, DATEEXAMPLE, n)
```

By changing `n` you will have some formatted results: ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187928%28v=sql.110%29.aspx))

```
20 = 120 = yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)

5 = dd-mm-yy

105 = dd-mm-yyyy

10 = mm-dd-yy

110 = mm-dd-yyyy
```